# spring boot 2.3.12.RELEASE integrated graphql、jdk1.8 Unable to start

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8

> WARN  AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext:559 -
> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'graphQLController': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'graphQL'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'graphQL' defined in class path resource
> [com/gtech/ecomm/graphql/config/GraphqlAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQL' parameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'graphQLBuilder' defined in class path
> resource
> [com/gtech/ecomm/graphql/config/GraphqlAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'graphQLBuilder'
> parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'graphQLSchema' defined in class path resource
> [com/gtech/ecomm/graphql/config/GraphqlAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate [graphql.schema.GraphQLSchema]: Factory method
> 'graphQLSchema' threw exception; nested exception is
> com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaClassScannerError: Type definition
> for root query type 'Query' not found!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.